# How to simulate multiple user input for JUnit4

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, user-input

' I have multiple user input prompts, is it possible to form a list of the user input and have it pick up the corresponding input when the time comes?
'

```
@Test
public void test1() {
    
    
    String simulatedUserInput = "1\n"+"2\n"+"3\n" ;
     
    InputStream savedStandardInputStream = System.in;
    System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(simulatedUserInput.getBytes()));

    // code that needs multiple user inputs

    System.setIn(savedStandardInputStream);

    
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(out));
    
    String[] args = {} ;
    Demo.main(args);
    
    String consoleOutPutString ="Enter side 1: "+ System.getProperty("line.separator")+"1"+ System.getProperty("line.separator"); 
           consoleOutPutString +="Enter side 2: "+ System.getProperty("line.separator")+"2"+ System.getProperty("line.separator"); 
           consoleOutPutString +="Enter side 3: "+ System.getProperty("line.separator")+"3"+ System.getProperty("line.separator"); 
           consoleOutPutString +="This is not a triangle."+ System.getProperty("line.separator"); 

    assertEquals(consoleOutPutString, out.toString());
    
    
}
```

}

'this code dosen't work'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZyW8.png)

Comment: Doesn’t work in what way?

Comment: the test still run in infinite loop

Comment: I think we’ll need to see the code under test to help

Comment: Shouldn’t it call `System.setIn(savedStandardInputStream)` _after_ `Demo.main(args)`?

Answer (score 0):

You may wrap the `System.in` using [term4j](https://github.com/dgroup/term4j):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
   new YourApp(
      new Stdin(),   // Stdin is a wrapper for Scanner.in
      new Stdout()   // Stdout is a wrapper for System.out
   ).start(args);
}
```

This is the [unit test](https://github.com/dgroup/term4j#stdin) for `Stdin`

```java
    @Test
    public void readFromStdin() {
        /**
         * The standard system input (stdin) which keeps the expected input lines in-memory
         *  instead of direct manipulations with {@link System#in} or {@link Console}.
         */
        final Input stdin = new Stdin(
            new InputOf(String.format("line1%nline2"))
        );
        MatcherAssert.assertThat(
            "The 1st line was read from console",
            stdin.value(),
            new IsEqual("line1")
        );
        MatcherAssert.assertThat(
            "The 2nd line was read from console",
            stdin.value(),
            new IsEqual("line2")
        );
    }
```

This is the [unit test](https://github.com/dgroup/term4j#stdout) for `Stdout`

```java
    /**
     * Simulate the STD print procedure using {@link StringWriter}.
     */
    @Test
    public void printToWriter() {
        // Write 4 lines delimited by `\n` or `\r\n` to the StringWriter
        final StringWriter swter = new StringWriter();
        final Output std = new Stdout(swter);
        std.print("line1", "line2");
        std.print("line3", "line4");
        // Check that the result string has 4 lines
        MatcherAssert.assertThat(
            "4 lines of text were printed to the output",
            swter.toString(),
            new HasLines("line1", "line2", "line3", "line4")
        );
    }
```

For your case, you may simulate the `System.in` and `System.out` in your test using following code:

```java
public class YourAppTest {

   @Test
   public void skeleton(){
      Input stdin = new Stdin(  
         new InputOf(String.format("line1%nline2"))  // expected multiple user input from terminal
      );
      StringWriter stdout = new StringWriter();  // the app output to terminal
      new YourApp(stdin, new Stdout(stdout))
          .start(...);
      MatcherAssert.assertThat(
          "4 lines of text were printed to the output",
          out.toString(),
          new HasLines("line1", "line2", "line3", "line4")
      );
   }
}
```